# start virtual tour with gmaps v2 for android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, virtual-tour

is there a way to open a virtual tour with google maps api v2 for Android? (something similar to this: https://www.google.com/maps/@37.772031,-122.432005,3a,75y,12.85h,79.63t/data=!3m5!1e1!3m3!1srR8mp3c5XZoAAAAGOphoBg!2e0!3e2 )

I would like to click on a place in a gmap and offer the possibility (among other informations) to open a virtual tour (even in a webview, but how can I create the above link?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Photo Sphere](http://www.google.com.au/maps/about/contribute/photosphere/) is an Android camera feature that allows you to create immersive [360 degree panoramas](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxz_qvna3EQ) - similar to [Street View](http://connect.dpreview.com/post/6192101318/google-street-view-virtual-tour-photo-sphere). You can take a series of photos and automatically turn them into a seamless 360 [degree panorama](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/2839084?hl=en). Then, you can easily share your photo sphere with [Google Maps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NPs3eIiWRaw).

[image]

In order to have the Google maps displayed into your App, you should include it into your activity:

```
MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**
     * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

}
```

[image]

And also include to your code a [marker](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/) for where you want to open your virtual tour:

```
// latitude and longitude
double latitude = ;
double longitude = ;

// create marker
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps ");

// adding marker
googleMap.addMarker(marker);
```

[image]

Then update it to interact accordingly to the current [position coordinates](http://android-er.blogspot.com.au/2013/01/google-maps-android-api-v2-example_5213.html) provided:

```
 public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

  if(markerClicked){

   if(polyline != null){
    polyline.remove();
    polyline = null;
   }

   rectOptions.add(marker.getPosition());
   rectOptions.color(Color.RED);
   polyline = myMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
  }else{
   if(polyline != null){
    polyline.remove();
    polyline = null;
   }

   rectOptions = new PolylineOptions().add(marker.getPosition());
   markerClicked = true;
  }

  return true;
 }

}
```

[image]

Once a Photo Sphere was made as an open format, anyone can create and view them on the web or on mobile devices, only having to use [Panorama Class/Interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/panorama/package-summary.html) for that:

```
// This listener will be called with information about the given panorama.
OnPanoramaInfoLoadedListener infoLoadedListener =
  new OnPanoramaInfoLoadedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPanoramaInfoLoaded(ConnectionResult result,
                                     Intent viewerIntent) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // If the intent is not null, the image can be shown as a
            // panorama.
            if (viewerIntent != null) {
                // Use the given intent to start the panorama viewer.
                startActivity(viewerIntent);
            }
        }

        // If viewerIntent is null, the image is not a viewable panorama.
    }
};

// Create client instance and connect to it.
PanoramaClient client = ...
...

// Once connected to the client, initiate the asynchronous check on whether
// the image is a viewable panorama.
client.loadPanoramaInfo(infoLoadedListener, panoramaUri);
```

[image]

Which will allow you to have a Photo Sphere [viewer](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2012/12/new-google-maps-android-api-now-part-of.html) as part of your App.